# Why does putting image on a black background cause a problem in numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def mycvshow(imagein, title='Image'): #title can be specified or left to the default
    cv2.imshow(title,imagein)
    cv2.waitKey()
    #cv2.destroyWindow(title)


img_gray=cv2.imread('cat.jpg',0)
big_picture=np.zeros((img_gray.shape[0]+1000,img_gray.shape[1]+1000))
big_picture[0:img_gray.shape[0],0:img_gray.shape[1]]=img_gray
mycvshow(big_picture)
```

The above is my code. I read in an image in grayscale and then put it in a large matrix of zeros. I expect it to return a picture of a cat with a black background but it just breaks the `mycvshow` function and shows an almost completely white picture of the cat on a black background and window displaying the image seems to have problems too. Everything goes perfectly if i just write `mycvshow(img_gray)`.

Comment: Use `dtype=np.uint8` with `np.zeros`.

Comment: Consider using `cv2.copyMakeBorder()` maybe

Comment: Divakar's comment is saying your image is 8-bit but the black background gets created 64-bit by default, so `imshow()` can't handle it.

Comment: It did indeed fix the problem but why are there different bits for grayscale images? Aren't 64 bit and 8bit classifications for colored image displays?

Comment: Because numpy arrays are generic datatype. You just happen to use them to represent an image.